# Music in Yuri on Ice in Season 1 Episode 12

Tags: music, yuri-on-ice

I would like to know if someone could tell me what is the name of the music in the finale scene, season 1 episode 12 at ~ 21 : 51 when Yuri and Viktor are skating together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t have access to the anime right now, so I’m going off my memory, but if I’m not mistaken, it’s “Stammi vicino.” For some reason, I’m having trouble finding an official recording, but [this](https://youtu.be/4IjMAGw2l3o) is someone’s performance of it with a piano transcription of the orchestra.